# Draw a bunch of elements generated by CUDA/OpenCL?

Tags: opengl, cuda

I'm new to graphics programming, and need to add on a rendering backend for a demo we're creating. I'm hoping you guys can point me in the right direction.

**Short version**: Is there any way to send OpenGL an array of data for distinct elements, without having to issue a draw command for each element distinctly?

**Long version**: We have a CUDA program (will eventually be OpenCL) which calculates a bunch of data for a bunch of objects for us. We then need to render these objects using, e.g., OpenGL.

The CUDA kernel can generate our vertices, and using OpenGL interop, it can shove these in an OpenGL VBO and not have to transfer the data back to host device memory. But the problem is we have a bunch (upwards of a million is our goal) distinct objects. It seems like our best bet here is allocating one VBO and putting every object's vertices into it. Then we can call glDrawArrays with offsets and lengths of each element inside that VBO.

*However,* each object may have a variable number of vertices (though the total vertices in the scene can be bounded.) I'd like to avoid having to transfer a list of start indices and lengths from CUDA -> CPU every frame, especially given that these draw commands are going right back to the GPU.

Is there any way to pack a buffer with data such that we can issue only one call to OpenGL to render the buffer, and it can render a number of distinct elements from that buffer?

(Hopefully I've also given enough info to avoid a XY problem here.)

Comment: Define "element". You say you're using a `glDrawArrays` command to render it. Are you rendering `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`s, `GL_TRIANGLES`, or something else? What primitive are you rendering? Also, if you render them all in one draw call, you won't be able to have any state changes between objects.

Comment: GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP at the moment (trying to draw segments of a 2D 'donut' as in [this graph](http://arstechnica.com/business/2011/04/web-browser-market-share-modern-browser-edition/)). But we want to generalize it to draw arbitrary elements in the futre.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to get away from understanding these as individual objects and making them a single large object drawn with a single draw call. The question is, what data is it that distinguishes the objects from each other, meaning what is it you change between the individual calls to `glDrawArrays/glDrawElements`?

If it is something simple, like a color, it would probably be easier to supply this an additional per-vertex attribute. This way you can render all objects as one single large object using a single draw call with the indiviudal sub-objects (which really only exist conceptually now) colored correctly. The memory cost of the additional attribute may be well worth it.

If it is something a little more complex (like a texture), you may still be able to index it using an additional per-vertex attribute, being either an index into a texture array (as texture arrays should be supported on CUDA/OpenCL-able hardware) or a texture coordinate into a particular subregion of a single large texture (a so-called texture atlas).

But if the difference between those objects is something more complex, as a different shader or something, you may really need to render individual objects and make individual draw calls. But you still don't need to neccessarily make a round-trip to the CPU. With the use of the [ARB_draw_indirect](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/draw_indirect.txt) extension (which is core since GL 4.0, I think, but may be supported on GL 3 hardware (and thus CUDA/CL-hardware), don't know) you can source the arguments to a `glDrawArrays/glDrawElements` call from an additional buffer (into which you can write with CUDA/CL like any other GL buffer). So you can assemble the offset-length-information of each individual object on the GPU and store them in a single buffer. Then you do your `glDrawArraysIndirect` loop offsetting into this single draw-indirect-buffer (with the offset between the individual objects now being constant).

---

But if the only reason for issuing multiple draw calls is that you want to render the objects as single `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`s or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`s (or, god beware, `GL_POLYGON`s), you may want to reconsider just using a bunch of `GL_TRIANGLES` so that you can render all objects in a single draw call. The (maybe) time and memory savings from using triangle strips are likely to be outweight by the overhead of multiple draw calls, especially when rendering many small triangle strips. If you really want to use strips or fans, you may want to introduce degenerate triangles (by repeating vertices) to seprate them from each other, even when drawn with a single draw call. Or you may look into the [`glPrimitiveRestartIndex`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glPrimitiveRestartIndex.xml) function introduced with GL 3.1.

Comment: ARB_draw_indirect looks like exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I need to make sure that our platform supports the extension (we eventually want to target WebCL, which looks like it doesn't support it, but we may be able to change it...)

If that doesn't work, I'll look into degenerate triangles (if you have any pointers for finding more info on that, please post them, if you don't mind.)

Comment: I'll also look into glPrimitiveRestartIndex, but it seems like you can only specify a single index. There's no way to drive it with a buffer/array? So you'd still need multiple calls + knowing the offsets.

Comment: @int3h So what is the reason for splitting it into multiple draw calls in the first place. If it was really just because of the use of triangle strips or fans (as otherwise primitive restart and degerate triangles wouldn't buy you anything, anyway), then why not just use a simple triangle set to draw the whole thing with a single draw call? This way you don't have to worry about any offsets or lengths as you can just draw the whole buffer as a list if triangles. Of course you know the triangles of a single draw call don't need to be connected in any way.

Comment: @int3h Otherwise, primitive restart is of course of help. You just say (in the host program) that a special index (say -1, or UINT_MAX) marks the end of a primtive. Then you draw the whole buffer with a single draw call (without worrying about any offsets or lengths) but beforehand you insert a vertex index of -1 (or UINT_MAX, or whatever) in the index buffer after each individual strip to differentiate them from each other (on the GPU, of course). But in this case you need to draw indexed primtives, using `glDrawElements`. But as said, first think if you even need multiple triangle strips!

Comment: "Of course you know the triangles of a single draw call don't need to be connected in any way."

I did not :) If you're saying this is a better way, I'll definitely look into implementing our drawing as this. 

And good catch on the glPrimitiveRestartIndex(). I misunderstood -- I thought it specified a specific index in the buffer that drawing would be restarted at. Didn't realize it specifies a value that the drawing restarts at every time it encounters it.

Looks like we have multiple options to do what we want. Thank you! You've been really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not optimal, but you could make a single glDrawArray on your whole buffer...

- If you use GL_TRIANGLES, you can fill your buffer with zeroes, and write only the needed vertices in your kernel. This way "empty" regions of your buffer will be drawn as 0-area polygons ( = degenerate polygons -> not drawn at all )
- If you use GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, you can do the same, but you'll have to duplicate your first vertex in order to make a fake triangle between (0,0,0) and your mesh.

This can seem overkill, but :
 - You'll have to be able to handle as many vertices anyway
 - degenerate triangles use no fillrate, so they are almost free (the vertex shader is still computed, though)

A probably better solution would be to use glDrawElements instead : In you kernel, you also generate an index list for your whole buffer, which will be able to completely skip regions of your buffer.